# text formatting in ReportParameter

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report

I have VS2008 and windows reports.
I want to pass to my text field parameter that will be automatically formatted as follows:

hello **you**

with something like:

```
ReportParameter ourRef = new ReportParameter("Message", "hello <strong>Mickey Mouse</strong>");
```

I know I can set data into pareameter, but how do I customise the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot have different formats within one textfield - you have to split it up.
So two parameters one for the standard format ("hello") and the other one which goes into a formated textfield ("you").